# GAE Servlet XML Response. How?

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine

I need to send XML response from my GAE servlet.
What I already have is:
- An instance of org.w3c.dom.Document populated with data
- HttpServletResponse (that gives me either a PrintWriter or a ServletOutputStream)

If XMLSerializer were whitelisted in GAE, I could finish the work. ..but it's not.

My question is: How to cook the food from these ingredients?
(without 3rd party libraries please)

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, ENCODING);
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", INDENT);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: Steven, you're such a great savior!